# Variables not accepting values passed from another class

Tags: c#

I am about to give up on this, i am trying to pass a string to another class and in that class save it to a List but it just wont do it. I know the List exists and works as i made a button that puts a string into that list and shows it in the listbox. But for some reason i just cant get it to work on the passed string.

It's two winforms as one let's the user give the info and then it's processed and passed to the another class which should then save into the List and then i call for a update which should show the List in the listbox.

Mainform (the one with the listbox)

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{        

    List<string> m_customers = new List<string>();    


    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }


    public void StringToList(string strnew)
    {           
        m_customers.Add(strnew);
        Updatelistbox();

        foreach (string custom in m_customers)
        {
            lstRegistry.Items.Add(custom);
        }
    }

    private void strtest(string strnew)
    {
        string userinfo = strnew;
        m_customers.Add(userinfo);
    }

    private void Updatelistbox()
    {
        lstRegistry.Items.Clear();
        for (int index = 0; index < m_customers.Count; index++)
        {
            lstRegistry.Items.Add(m_customers[index]);
        }
    }      

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ContactForm frm = new ContactForm())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 
        lstRegistry.Items.Add("Hey this works atleast...");

        m_customers.Add("add this to List");  //This works as this line becomes more and more.
        foreach (string custom in m_customers)
        {
            lstRegistry.Items.Add(custom);
        }        
    }
}
```

The inputform

```
public partial class ContactForm : Form
{
    private ContactFiles.Contact m_contact = new ContactFiles.Contact();
    private ContactFiles.Email m_email = new ContactFiles.Email();
    private ContactFiles.Phone m_phone = new ContactFiles.Phone();
    private ContactFiles.Adress m_adress = new ContactFiles.Adress();

    private bool m_closeForm;

    public ContactForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeGUI();
    }

    private void InitializeGUI()
    {
        txtFirstName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtLastName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtHomePhone.Text = string.Empty;
        txtCellPhone.Text = string.Empty;
        txtEmailBusiness.Text = string.Empty;
        txtEmailPrivate.Text = string.Empty;
        txtStreet.Text = string.Empty;
        txtCity.Text = string.Empty;
        txtZipCode.Text = string.Empty;
        FillCountryComboBox();
        cmbCountries.Items.AddRange(FillCountryComboBox()); cmbCountries.SelectedIndex = 5;
        m_closeForm = true;
    }


    public string[] FillCountryComboBox()
    {
        string[] m_countryStrings = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Countries));

        for (int index = 0; index < m_countryStrings.Length - 1; index++)
        {
            m_countryStrings[index] = m_countryStrings[index].Replace("_", " ");
        }
        return m_countryStrings;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        string a_country = cmbCountries.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var oAdress = new ContactFiles.Adress(txtStreet.Text, txtCity.Text, txtZipCode.Text, a_country);
        string adresslist = oAdress.ToString();            
        var oEmail = new ContactFiles.Email(txtEmailBusiness.Text, txtEmailPrivate.Text);
        string emaillist = oEmail.ToString();            
        var oPhones = new ContactFiles.Phone(txtHomePhone.Text, txtCellPhone.Text);
        string phonelist = oPhones.ToString();
        //This is actually working, the string is passed OK.            
        //MainForm strin = new MainForm();            
        var oContact = new ContactFiles.Contact(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
        string namelist = oContact.ToString();

        //Create string from input and send to MainForm.StringToList()
        MainForm instance = new MainForm();
        string strnew = string.Format("{0,-3} {1, -10} {2, -20} {3, -30}", namelist, phonelist, emaillist, adresslist);
        instance.StringToList(strnew);


        this.Close();
    }

    private ContactFiles.Contact Contacts
    {
        get { return m_contact; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                m_contact = value;                
        }
    }

    public ContactFiles.Email Email
    {
        get { return m_email; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != null)
            m_email = value; 
        }
    }

    public ContactFiles.Phone Phone
    {
        get { return m_phone; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                m_phone = value;
        }
    }

    private ContactFiles.Adress Adress
    {
        get { return m_adress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                m_adress = value;
        }
    }

    private void ContactForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_closeForm)
            e.Cancel = false;  //Close the Contact form.
        else
            e.Cancel = true; //Do not close (user has chosen Cancel)
    }      
}
```

There are as you can see some more classes that handles the user input that contains constructors but they all work as i can create the string from all the user input but then i fails big time for me and its like 3 days now and i still can't find the problem.  :'(

Any idea on how to fix my problem?!? I just cant find the issue.

Comment: Describe "doesn't work". Runtime exceptions or compile errors?

Comment: Can you specify where in all of this code it's actually failing?  What line is setting the string to the target variable and on what line are you reading it and expecting it to be there when it isn't there?

Comment: The List does not get the value.

Comment: Which List does not get which value when? Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: You need to narrow that down. That's way too much code for us to read and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 MainForm instance = new MainForm();
    string strnew = string.Format("{0,-3} {1, -10} {2, -20} {3, -30}", namelist, phonelist, emaillist, adresslist);
    instance.StringToList(strnew);
```

This is bad. You are creating a new instance of main form (with new list) instead of using old one. Pass list in conctructor of Contact form and add value there.

```
List<string> m_customers;

public ContactForm(List<string> list) : this()
{
   m_customers = list;
}
```

Creating form code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ContactForm frm = new ContactForm(m_customers))
    {
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Now you could add values to the list.

Update: Bring your StringToList method to the contact form, make it private and use it in the contact form instance.

Comment: I u where here i plant a big wet kiss in your face!! :P Thanks alot!!! I have been at this for 3 days!! I knew there where some small thing i were missing...finally it places the string into the list. Thanks alot for the help!!! Now i can star to adress the other million small details but thats why we have nights, right?! ;) Thanks again Dantix!!

Answer (score 1):

You might try making your main form have an instance of the input form and not vice versa. The main form is ultimately going to hold the data. Let the input form be a new instance and return the values that way.

Comment: Absolutely! I was doing it backwards :P it's late here ;) Thanks!!